# Can I have dynamic FROM Clause in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I'm currently working with my report parameter **list of value** that is dependent in another parameter. 
I have come up with this idea, is there any possible way to for this to work?

```
WITH A AS (
SELECT DISTINCT columnA1 FROM Table1 
UNION SELECT DISTINCT columnA2 FROM Table1 
UNION SELECT DISTINCT columnA3 FROM Table1)

WITH B AS (SELECT DISTINCT columnB1 FROM Table1 
UNION SELECT DISTINCT columnB2 FROM Table1 
UNION SELECT DISTINCT columnB3 FROM Table1)

Select * from CASE WHEN (:PM_Parameter1 = 'A')
THEN A
ELSE B
END;
```

Comment: Which RDBMS you're using?

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT since UNION will remove duplicates anyway.

Comment: @Kacper I'm using Oracle SQL

Comment: @jarlh Thank so much, its a big help. Take care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is Oracle SQL, you can use a the EXISTS function to check for the parameter value, then combine the sets using UNION.

Try playing with this SQL:

```
select * from
(
select 'A' from dual 
union 
select 'B' from dual
)
where exists 
    (SELECT 'Y'
    FROM dual
    where 'parameter' = 'parameter'
    )
union
select * from
(
select 'X' from dual 
union 
select 'Y' from dual
)
where exists 
    (SELECT 'Y'
    FROM dual
    where 'parameter' != 'parameter'
    )
```

If you reverse both the conditions `'parameter' = 'parameter'` and `'parameter' != 'parameter'`, it will return two different row sets.

I am sure this can be optimized again, hope it works out for you.

Comment: thanks a lot man, I'll try to use this as soon as i can. I'll be working on it and i'll give you an update